# How to precisely know when a user touches a BoxCollider2D

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I want to detect on an Android device every time the user touches a GameObject with a BoxCollider2D attached to it so that code can be executed each time.

In my case the user swipes over the GameObject multiple times thus they probably won't lift the finger from the screen until they need to or a specific condition is met.

Here's an example image:

[image: Case example]

Answer (score 3):

> the user swipes over the GameObject multiple times thus they probably
>   won't lift the finger from the screen until they need to or a specific
>   condition is met.

Since the user is not required to remove finger from the screen, you can check for swipe over a 2D GameObject with `TouchPhase.Moved` and `RaycastHit2D`. `TouchPhase.Began` should be used to detect touch only.

```
void Update()
{
    //Check for Press
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector2 fingerRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            RaycastHit2D objectHit = Physics2D.Raycast(fingerRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (objectHit)
            {
                //We hit something
                if (objectHit.collider.name == "myGameObjectName")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touched Finger on GameObject: " + objectHit.collider.name);
                }
            }
        }

        //Check if we moved the finger(while press is still down)
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 fingerRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            RaycastHit2D objectHit = Physics2D.Raycast(fingerRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (objectHit)
            {
                //We hit something while moving the finger
                if (objectHit.collider.name == "myGameObjectName")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Moved Finger on GameObject: " + objectHit.collider.name);
                }
            }
        }

        //Check for release
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            Debug.Log("Released Finger!");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

> The code doesn't detect all the swipes over the GameObject. It works
>   well only if you swipe just a little around it.

You can have your own custom move phase. Replace `if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` with  `if (Input.GetTouch(i).deltaPosition.magnitude > validMoveMagnitude)`.

`validMoveMagnitude`  is defined as  `float validMoveMagnitude = 1.5f;`.

**EDIT 3**:

If small move is still not being detected, you can make a variable that stores last touch pos then compare it with the new touch pos.

```
Vector3 lastPos;

void Update()
{
    //Check for Press
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            lastPos = Input.GetTouch(i).position;
            Vector2 fingerRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            RaycastHit2D objectHit = Physics2D.Raycast(fingerRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (objectHit)
            {
                //We hit something
                if (objectHit.collider.name == "myGameObjectName")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touched Finger on GameObject: " + objectHit.collider.name);
                }
            }
        }

        //Get current Pos
        Vector3 currentPos = Input.GetTouch(i).position;

        //Check if we moved
        if (currentPos != lastPos)
        {
            //Update Last Pos
            lastPos = currentPos;
            Debug.Log("Finger Moved!" + lastPos);

            Vector2 fingerRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            RaycastHit2D objectHit = Physics2D.Raycast(fingerRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (objectHit)
            {
                //We hit something while moving the finger
                if (objectHit.collider.name == "myGameObjectName")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Moved Finger on GameObject: " + objectHit.collider.name);
                }
            }
        }

        //Check for release
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            // Debug.Log("Released Finger!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't detect all the swipes over the GameObject. It works well only if you swipe just a little around it.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the lower the validMoveMagnitude the shorter can be the movement for the condition to detect there's actually been movement, but the condition still won't be met every time the finger swipes over the GameObject.

Comment: Check my 3rd EDIT. If that doesn't work then I don't know what else would work for you. The last solution is very sensitive to movement and should do the trick. Let me know.

Comment: The movement detection works fine but the collision does not. "Finger moved" always logs while the finger is moving but the collision with the collider is only detected at times. Might be a collision layer problem or more colliders overlapping?

Comment: "but the collision does not". You mean raycast does not work? If this is so then, 1.You have to run it on the physical device(Android or iOS). 2.You must change `myGameObjectName` in  `if (objectHit.collider.name == "myGameObjectName")` to the name of your GameOject you want to to detect the swipe on.  You can even remove that if statement and put the code you want to run during swipe directly inside `if (objectHit)`.

Comment: I did change myGameObjectName with the name of the GameObject and try on an Android phone. The raycast does work but it doesn't all the times. If I swipe many times over the GameObject the code inside the raycast hit condition will be executed less times than the times I swipe over it.

Comment: This code is working on my side 100%. I don't know what your problem is. All you have to do is detect swipe once then do something.

Comment: This didn't work for me and had to create a GameObject with only a BoxCollider2D attached to it and set its position to the touch position in Update(). Then I use OnTriggerEnter2D to detect each time that GameObject touches the other GameObject. This is the closest I got to detect every time the user touches the GameObject (though it still isn't detected 100% of the times). I also reduced the Fixed Timestep (seemed to help detecting more touches).

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script to that gameobject with box collider.
You can detect with mouse pointer enter event which also works with Android. Just tried with a basic canvas with a half sized panel attached to box collider 2D.

```
using UnityEngine;using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler 
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GameObject currentGo;
        currentGo = eventData.pointerEnter;
        if (currentGo.tag == "GameObjectWithCollider2D" || currentGo.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("This has Box Collider 2D"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works on UI only. My GameObject is a SpriteRenderer with a BoxCollider2D.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?